# Links not rendering correctly in email send from console

Tags: cakephp, command-line-interface, cakephp-3.x

I have the following code that sends my email:

```
/**
 * @param array $to
 * @param string $subject
 * @param array $vars
 * @param string $template
 * @param array $from
 */
public function sendEmail(array $to, $subject, array $vars, $template = 'default', array $from = ['dev@example.com' => 'Online'])
{
    $transport = 'default';
    if (Configure::read('debug')) {
        $transport = 'dev';
    }
    $mailer = new Email($transport);
    if ($this->isCommandLineInterface()) {
        $mailer->setDomain('http://local.peepznew.com');
    }
    $this->addRecipients($mailer, $to);
    $mailer->setFrom($from);
    $mailer->setSubject($subject);
    $mailer->setTemplate($template);
    if (isset($vars['preheaderText']) === false) {
        $vars['preheaderText'] = '';
    }
    $vars['subject'] = $subject;
    $mailer->setViewVars($vars);
    $mailer->setEmailFormat('both');
    $mailer->send();
}
```

This code is called from the web interface as well as from the command line. After struggling to get the full url to display in messages sent from the command line, I read the docs and came across [this](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-emails-from-cli):

[image]

Which is why I'm doing the setDomain call. I run my code again, and it still doesn't have full Urls. So I created the exact same function in both the web interface and cli, that looks like this:

```
$this->sendEmail(
    ['my.email@example.com'],
    'Test Email',
    [
        'title' => 'We need to select another peep',
        'showFooterLinks' => true,
    ]
);
die;
```

The default template looks like so (it literally only has this one line in it):

```
echo $this->Html->link('test link', ['controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'select_staff', 1, '_full' => true]);
```

The emails from the web interface, using the code above, sends perfect. Full URLs and everything. However from the cli, it just sends `/jobs/select_staff/1`.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: what does $this->isCommandLineInterface() do? Are you sure the code inside the if is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs closely, they say that the domain set via `setDomain()` is being used when generating message IDs, ie it's being used in an E-Mail header.

Generating links is something completely different, and is affected by the `App.fullBaseUrl` configuration option, which is by default derived from `env('HTTP_HOST')` in your applications `config/bootstrap.php`, unless already configured in `config/app.php`.

It's also possible to configure the base URL separately for the CLI environment in your `config/bootstrap_cli.php` file, there should already be a commented snippet for doing so that looks like this:

```
// Set the fullBaseUrl to allow URLs to be generated in shell tasks.
// This is useful when sending email from shells.
//Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', php_uname('n'));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Console Tools, Shells & Tasks > Routing in the Console Environment](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#routing-in-the-console-environment)**
- **[Source > cakephp/app > config/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.6.1/config/bootstrap.php#L133)**
- **[Source > cakephp/app > config/bootstrap_cli.php](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.6.1/config/bootstrap_cli.php#L26)**
- **[Source > cakephp/app > config/app.php](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.6.1/config/app.default.php#L31)**